# How to check if key is pressed in a text box Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, input

I'm using Visual Studio C# and trying to check if the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key has been pressed while in a text box

```
private void PasswordTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(keyenterhasbeenpressed) //I dont know what to put here
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed the enter key");
    }
}
```

So when someone clicks enter in that text box it will do something.

Comment: e.KeyCode contains the key code. Example:  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) { ... }

Answer (score 1):

The `TextChanged` event isn't really suited for checking for keypresses. 
It's best used to examine the sender object which is the textbox itself.

To check for the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key you can do the following:

```
private void PasswordTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed the enter key");
    }
}
```

or

```
private void PasswordTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{        
    if(e.KeyChar == 13) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed the enter key");
    }
}
```

It depends on what event best suits your needs.
You can always put a break point (assuming visual studio) and check what data is available to you in the eventargs and sender object

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to link the function with the key press event of the textbox add the following code in the designer.cs of the form

```
this.textbox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.OnKeyDownHandler);
```

Now define the function 'OnKeyDownHandler' in the cs file of the same form

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {

       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
       {
       //enter key has been pressed
       // add your code
       }

}
```

Comment: You should never modify the `Designer.cs` manually with the editor.

Comment: they are visible to be modified if required,